# RDLC file opens as text only not in the designer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, rdlc

I have an RDLC file that opens as text only (xml) not in the designer,
how can I force it back to default to open with the designer.  (I need to go back and forth).

I swear I saw this on Stack already, but for the google of me I can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had this issue...

I resolved by adding a new Report to the project, which opened in the designer.

After the designer opened correctly, the existing reports also opened in the designer as not as XML.

Answer (score 1):

This problem comes when we change the default settings for any file type in visual studio.

Follow the steps given below to fix such issues:

- You can right click on the file!
- Select open with
- Click on Report Designer.
- Click on 'Set as Default'
- Click OK

You should be all set now. It will now always open in Report Designer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue in Visual Studio 2022. The reason for the problem is that the Microsoft RDLC report designer is disabled. After enabling it, the issue disappeared. To solve the problem, you need to do the following: Extensions -> Installed -> Microsoft RDLC Report Designer -> Enabled.